# SQL command not properly ended with insert statement

Tags: database, oracle, insert, rows, dml

hen I try to insert multiple rows of values, I write exactly the statement below, but get an error that "SQL command not properly ended". I cannot see where the error comes from, could anyone help me with this?

```
INSERT INTO employees
VALUES 
(100, 'Patel', 'Ralph', 22333, 'rpatel@mail.com',1, NULL, 'Sales Rep'),
(101, 'Denis', 'Betty', 33444, 'bdenis@mail.com', 4, NULL, 'Sales Rep'),
(102, 'Biri', 'Ben', 44555, 'bbrir@mail.com', 2, NULL, 'Sales Rep'),
(103, 'Newman', 'Chad', 66777, 'cnewman@mail.com', 3,  NULL, 'Sales Rep'),
(104, 'Ropeburn', 'Andrey', 77888, 'aropeburn@mail.com', 1, NULL, 'Sales Rep');
```

Comment: please tag your database as well

Comment: I think, there is no problem with insert query.

Comment: this is a fine insert statement , it works perfectly , check it out in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db5e7cebd4187d77f20f73b2abae2d61)

Comment: First make up your mind: MySQL? Oracle? They are not the same product, and what works in one may very well fail in the other. I am talking about your tags, at the bottom of your post; please click "Edit tags" and remove the tags that don't apply to your question.

Comment: It's for sql server and mysql. Please check my answer for oracle.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, these are really helpful for me as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work in sql server and mysql. For oracle:

```
INSERT INTO employees 
  WITH emp AS ( 
    SELECT 100, 'Patel', 'Ralph', 22333, 'rpatel@mail.com',1, NULL, 'Sales Rep'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 101, 'Denis', 'Betty', 33444, 'bdenis@mail.com', 4, NULL, 'Sales Rep'  FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 102,'Biri', 'Ben', 44555, 'bbrir@mail.com', 2, NULL, 'Sales Rep' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 103,'Newman', 'Chad', 66777, 'cnewman@mail.com', 3,  NULL, 'Sales Rep'     FROM dual union all
    select 104, 'Ropeburn', 'Andrey', 77888, 'aropeburn@mail.com', 1, NULL, 'Sales Rep'from dual
  ) select * from emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If DBMS == OracleDB then it does not support more than one data block in `INSERT .. VALUES`. Use `INSERT .. SELECT` instead:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees
SELECT 100, 'Patel', 'Ralph', 22333, 'rpatel@mail.com',1, NULL, 'Sales Rep' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 'Denis', 'Betty', 33444, 'bdenis@mail.com', 4, NULL, 'Sales Rep' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 'Biri', 'Ben', 44555, 'bbrir@mail.com', 2, NULL, 'Sales Rep' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 103, 'Newman', 'Chad', 66777, 'cnewman@mail.com', 3,  NULL, 'Sales Rep' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 104, 'Ropeburn', 'Andrey', 77888, 'aropeburn@mail.com', 1, NULL, 'Sales Rep' FROM DUAL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28d70404d37c5e00c791db125f2aa905)

Alternatively you may use 5 separate queries:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (100, 'Patel', 'Ralph', 22333, 'rpatel@mail.com',1, NULL, 'Sales Rep');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (101, 'Denis', 'Betty', 33444, 'bdenis@mail.com', 4, NULL, 'Sales Rep');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (102, 'Biri', 'Ben', 44555, 'bbrir@mail.com', 2, NULL, 'Sales Rep');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (103, 'Newman', 'Chad', 66777, 'cnewman@mail.com', 3,  NULL, 'Sales Rep');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (104, 'Ropeburn', 'Andrey', 77888, 'aropeburn@mail.com', 1, NULL, 'Sales Rep');
```

Comment: I tried INSERT ... SELECT. It works perfect. Thank you so much. I didn't realize these statement work differently on different servers!